# Steps to take backup of entire salesforce applicaion in eclipse

Tags: sandbox

Please give me the Steps to take backup of entire salesforce applicaion in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have use this way in Uban2 OS. first you have install **Force.com Plugins** and follow the steps below for backup your developed application.

- Create new project and select Force.com
- Enter username, password,security Token
- Select Environment in which you have to take backup e.g Sandbox.

Now Select options which way you have to use for download your data. After that show the list of folder in which you have to find your folder Like  Object,Trigger,Dashboards etc... click on finished then your selected data start download in your Eclipse .

I hope this might be useful for you if i miss any point or wrong then correct me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to backup meta data then create a new project using eclipse and then use a version control system like git or svn to back it up.

You cannot backup data using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Using eclipse you can take backup of metadata by creating a project as mentioned in previous answers. But each time when you need to take backup, you have to refresh metadata from server and back it up manually.

If you use force.com migration tool, you can schedule this metadata exports. If you want to backup data in your organization, use command line data loader. Both metadata export using force.com migration tool and data export using command line data loader can be scheduled to run. So you can schedule weekly/monthly backup of entire org this way.